# converting csv into map using first row as key and columns values as array/list

Tags: java

I've this format data in csv-

```
20017,20018,20019
10,20,30
20,30,40
```

so I want this in map of below format using lambda expression-

```
Map<Integer,Double[]> = new HashMap<>();
[20017={10,20},20018={20,30}, 20019={30,40}]
```

Comment: Some hint: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: What problems are you facing? Reading the file? Parsing the content? Building the map? What did you try so far?

Comment: List<String> columns;
        List<List<String>> values;
        try(BufferedReader br= Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("test.csv"))) {
            String firstLine=br.readLine();
            if(firstLine==null) throw new IOException("empty file");
            columns= Arrays.asList(firstLine.split(","));

            values = br.lines()
                    .map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(",")))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(columns);
            System.out.println(values);

Comment: I'm not able to tie back the first row as key and all values for it as list

Comment: parsing the csv is not an issue, I'm not sure how to covert the data into mentioned format as columns can be many and each columns first value is key and remaining is values

Comment: @ram Don't post code in a comment. **Edit** the question and show your code there, so it is better formatted and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   try(BufferedReader bufferedReader= Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("test.csv"))) {
        CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(bufferedReader);
        Map<String,Integer> hearders = parser.getHeaderMap();
        Map<String,List<Double>> data = new HashMap<>();

        parser.getRecords().stream().forEach(rec -> {
            hearders.entrySet().forEach( head ->{
                data.computeIfAbsent(head.getKey(), k-> new ArrayList<>()).add(Double.parseDouble(rec.get(head.getValue())));
            });
        });
        System.out.println(data);
    }
```

Comment: This is working code, please let me know if this can be done in better way.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic could be like this:

1. Read first line and `split(",")`. The array length is the `numberOfColumns`. Put the array aside.
2. Create a `List<List<Double>>` and add `numberOfColumns` lists to the outer list.
3. Read the rest of the lines. For each line, `split(",")` and parse each value to `Double` and add to corresponding column-list.
4. When done reading, use `toArray()` to convert `List<Double>` to `Double[]`, and build final `Map<Integer,Double[]>` with keys from array in step 1.